# Problem with looping until reaching certain amount

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongoose, discord.js

I'm making a giveaway discord bot with xp system. Adding xp to the user who has won works but automatically adding him a  new level if he has enough xp don't. This code gives user too many levels

ex: `User is level 1. He wins 1000xp from giveaway and his level should automatically increased to 10 (You can calculate that with the formula below)`

`winner` is the person who won giveaway

`100 * x * (x / 20) + (x * 50)` is the formula for calculating new level xp

```js
let prize = args[1]

xp.findOne({
  userID: winner.id
}, (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err
  if (!data) {
    const newData = new xp({
      serverID: message.guild.id,
      name: winner.tag,
      userID: winner.id,
      xp: parseInt(prize),
      level: 1,
    })

    let nxtLvl = newData.level + 1
    let newLevel = 100 * nxtLvl * (nxtLvl / 20) + (nxtLvl * 50)

    for (var i = 0; i < newLevel; i++) {
      if (newLevel <= newData.xp) {
        newData.level = newData.level + 1
      }
    }

    newData.save().catch(e => console.log(e))
  })
```

Comment: So, question.  Looking at your for loop, I'm not sure why you are even looping.  The logic within does not use the `i` at all.

Comment: I just tried something with looping and `i` because that seemed the most logical to me. I'm sorry if that's totally dumb

Comment: Can you explain what that block of logic is intended to do?

Comment: It should increment `i` value until user can't level up anymore.

Comment: Shouldn't the logic be more like, user receives xp because they won.  Add xp.  Then check if total exp exceeds next level threshold, and if so, increment level?  Also please review your snippet.  I edited it to make the indentation more readable and it looks like you have a syntax error and incomplete logic in your snippet your provided us

Comment: Yes that's what i'm doing in the for loop. But I want to do
`User wins 1k xp and with that 1k xp he can skip 4 levels.` that's why i'm looping with i to check how many levels he can skip. And meanwhile i'm looping i'm adding level too

Comment: How do you know logically that 1000 xp equates to needing to jump 4 levels?

Comment: That was just example so you know why i'm trying to for loop with `i`

Comment: Can you answer that though?  Because we need to understand your logic, in order to have any insight into how it would/could be implemented

Comment: As I said i want to automatically increment user's level with the xp he won. Because right now if he won and he checks his xp status it's ex: `1000/150` to new level and I want to skip these levels so he ends up ex: `1000/1150` (the 1150 is the xp needed to new level)

Comment: and his level will be increase by ex: 5

Comment: Ok, so disregarding that for a second.  You are currently setting the newData.level to 1 every time, and so `100 * nxtLvl * (nxtLvl / 20) + (nxtLvl * 50)` will always result in a value of `120`, because the nxtLvl will always be 2.  So your for loop going from `0` to < `120`, will loop 120 times

Comment: Oooh that's why my level was nonstop 120. Also edited the question for betting understanding